# Undo svn changelist

Tags: svn

I added a directory in svn by svn add command and there is one modified file. So my svn status command was showing me

```
$ svn status
A       app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Store
A       app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Store/switcher.phtml
M       app/code/local/Derm/Customersignup/controllers/AccountController.php
```

I just wanted to commit `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Store` and file inside it. So I used `svn changelist` command. I have used it earlier to commit selected files and finds much handy. But it skipped directory adding but added file inside. I searched about it found that `svn checkout` can add directories.

```
$svn changelist my-changelist app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Store/
```

Now my svn status became

```
$svn status
M       app/code/local/Derm/Customersignup/controllers/AccountController.php
--- Changelist 'my-changelist':
M       app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/store/switcher.phtml
A       app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Store/Switcher.php
```

I am afraid that if i commit this changelist then my store directory will not be commit and may be there will some exception as well.
**So I want to undo my changelist changes**, revert unwanted modified file `app/code/local/Derm/Customersignup/controllers/AccountController.php` and use direct `svn commit` command.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'checklist'. It's a 'change list'.

Comment: You're showing a different list of files in the two different executions of `svn status`. That shouldn't happen, unless something else is going on that you haven't told us about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to see what is committed is to leave out the `-m` commit message when committing:

```
$ svn commit --changelist my-changelist
```

This will bring up the editor where you can enter you commit message. On the bottom will be displayed a complete list of everything (files and directories) being committed. This can help you verify that you are committing what you think you're committing and ease your concerns.

You can specify all the files you want to commit on the command line:

```
$ cd app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block
$ svn commit Store Store/switcher.phtml
```

This will commit what you want without having to define a changelist.

If you want to delete a changelist, you can use the `svn changelist --remove` command to remove items from a changelist, and once the changelist is empty, it will no longer be defined.

Go ahead and try the first command using the changelist and when the editor opens up, you'll see what will be committed. If it's not what you want, leave the message empty and abort the commit.

Answer (score -1):

You could follow these steps :

1. Use `svn changelist --remove` to remove changelist association, and then
2. `svn revert app/code/local/Derm/Customersignup/controllers/AccountController.php` to revert to previous revision (discard change)
3. `svn ci` to commit all your files, **or**
4. `svn ci app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Store` to commit only the folder `Store` and its content

Comment: There is no such thing as 'svn checklist'.

Comment: @bmargulies Thank you for seeing this, I fixed it, I got confused because of OP's typo :(

Comment: `svn changelist --remove` gives an error to me: `svn: E205001: Not enough arguments provided`. Can you please expand ?